# CSS3 TextArea Highlight Color

Tags: colors, css, selection, highlight

I've been using the following CSS3 option to change the highlight color of text on a webpage. However, the only element on the webpage is a textarea, and the following CSS doesn't seem to do anything.

```
::selection { background:#B9B9B9; color:#000000; }
```

Am I doing it wrong? Is it possible to change the highlight color of a textarea? Or am I just wasting my time?

Comment: Is that the exact CSS style you are using? As it should be textarea::selection { ... }

Comment: Hmm. I can't get it to work even with the textarea::selection { ... } syntax.  I've also tried #editor.::selection { ... } but that also doesn't work. I don't suppose it could be a browser issue? I've tested it in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and IE8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the vendor extension versions [`-moz-selection` and `-webkit-selection`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html):

```
::selection { background:#B9B9B9; color:#000000; }
::-moz-selection { background:#B9B9B9; color:#000000; }
::-webkit-selection { background:#B9B9B9; color:#000000; }
```

Note that the selection pseudo has been [removed from the current draft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A%3Aselection#Specifications).

Comment: NB: `::selection` is back in [CSS Pseudo-Elements Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/)