# Jquery: possible to change the text selection color in a textarea with jquery? css doesn't work :(

Tags: jquery, css, selection, textselection

```
textarea::selection {
background:#0099ff;}
```

That's how you specify a text selection color for chrome in CSS, i know it's different for different browsers but I wanted to know if there's a way to change the selection color inside of a textarea, because the code above wont work for chrome, now, in the code above if i changed `textarea` to `p` then it would work on all the paragraphs. I noticed that the code above does work if I select the ENTIRE textarea, but not when selecting text in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't change the selection color for a textarea, you can only change it for non-input objects.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% true. It should work in paragraphing, but not any other element.
Try:

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481890/css3-textarea-highlight-color) for a related answer to a related question.

> ### Specifications
>
> The ::selection CSS pseudo-element was drafted for CSS Selectors Level 3 but removed >
>   before it reaches the Recommendation status. Despite this, it's implemented in some >browsers, which will probably retain experimental support for it.
>
> Right now, the ::selection CSS pseudo-element is not in any specification on the standard track.
>
> ### Browser compatibility
>
> Chrome: 1.x, Firefox (Gecko): 1.0 (with -moz), Internet Explorer: 9, Opera: 9.5 or later, Safari: 1.1

**Note:** As said in that answer in the link, [removed from the draft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A%3Aselection#Specifications).

So basically, 
you **can:**

- Change non-selection color

but you **can't:**

- Change the selection color (not yet)

<sup>**Note:** Not all stuff in this answer maybe true.</sup>