# change focus select highlight color of text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, highlight

How do I change the standard highlight color that is applied when you select the data from a text input field?

For example:

1.) User clicks on the text field box.
2.) The contents get highlighted.
3.) I'd like to change this color.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $url;?>" size="40" id="selecturl"/><br/><br/>

<script language="JavaScript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#selecturl').focus();
    jQuery('#selecturl').select();
});
</script>
<style>
input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}   
</style>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is vague. Please specify what you mean when you say "grey highlight color." UI elements such as text inputs can also differ between browsers. EDIT: also, do you have any CSS for us to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy - see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Intacto/k8L6u/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type='text/css'>
    input[type=text]:focus {
        background-color: lightblue;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px indigo;
        border: 1px solid indigo;
    }
    input::selection { background:black; color: white;}
    input::-moz-selection { background:black; color:white; }
    input::-webkit-selection { background:black; color:white; }
  </style>
</head><body>

  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $url;?>" size="40" id="selecturl"/><br/><br/>

  <input type="text" value="URL" size="40" id="selecturl"/><br/><br/>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an id to the input like `id="input"` than add this line in your css file

```
#input { outline-color: red; }
```

or you can also do this witout adding any id, but it will affect all your inputs in your page

```
input { outline-color: red; }
```

If you want to do this using jQuery :

```
$("#input").css("outline-color","red"); // with id
$("input").css("outline-color","red"); // witout id
```

<kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q8gR/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Maybe it did not answer the question, but it's useful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the highlight color for a tex you can try with CSS3.

```
::selection { background:#B9B9B9; color:#000000; }
::-moz-selection { background:#B9B9B9; color:#000000; }
::-webkit-selection { background:#B9B9B9; color:#000000; }
```

I made a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/QPLqQ/

---

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3482668/3625883